# Filtering With Multiple Inputs from InputBox

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, inputbox, autofilter

I'm trying to filter rows (keeping only values inputted) with multiple inputs to InputBox. With the values inputted, I want to create an array with which to AutoFilter my data.

What I have so far is below.

I'm stuck at splitting the inputs into an array?

```
Dim ticker As Variant
ticker = InputBox("Enter Stock Tickers Separated by Commas")

Dim MyArray As String
MyArray = Split(ticker, ",")


Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria:=MyArray
```

Comment: Try `Dim MyArray As Variant`

Comment: That seemed to help with the split function but now it's stopping at the AutoFilter. Any advice?

Comment: Whoops, just realized I left out the 1 after Criteria. Final Code:

    Dim ticker As Variant
    ticker = InputBox("Enter Stock Tickers Separated by Commas")
    
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = Split(ticker, ",")
    
    
    Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=Array(MyArray), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Answer (score 0):

Final code:

```
Dim ticker As Variant
ticker = InputBox("Enter Stock Tickers Separated by Commas")

Dim MyArray As Variant
MyArray = Split(ticker, ",")


Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=Array(MyArray), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```